# Regex to split on spaces, except those within ( ) braces

Tags: java, regex

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

so my output should be like: here i need to ignore the index after 1 or 2nd postion

```
Mozilla/5.0
Windows NT 6.1
```

or

```
Mozilla/5.0
Windows NT 6.1
AppleWebKit/537.36
KHTML, like Gecko
Chrome/65.0.3325.181
Safari/537.36
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing? Please post an [mcve]. Also your output doesn't match your question - if you split by spaces that are outside the braces, you would still see the braces in the output.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the parentheses only appear around terms which themselves contain whitespace.  These parentheses help to distinguish between whitespace which is part of a term, and whitespace which is there to separate terms.  In fact, without parentheses, we might not be able to easily separate out the terms.

The approach below takes a two fold approach.  First, we split on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\)\s)|(?=\s\()
```

This will separate terms in parentheses onto separate lines, and series of terms not in parentheses will still be clustered together:

```
Mozilla/5.0
 (Windows NT 6.1) 
AppleWebKit/537.36
 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

The second step is to iterate this result, and *again* split each term.  This time, we can legitimately split on whitespace, knowing that the only whitespace still present is meant for separating terms.

```
String input = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\)\\s)|(?=\\s\\()");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (String part : parts) {
    part = part.trim();
    if (part.length() == 0) continue;

    if (part.charAt(0) == '(') {
        results.add(part.substring(1, part.length()-1));
    }
    else {
        String[] items = part.split("\\s+");
        for (String item : items) {
            results.add(item);
        }
    }
}
for (String result : results) {
    System.out.println(result);
}

Mozilla/5.0
Windows NT 6.1
AppleWebKit/537.36
KHTML, like Gecko
Chrome/65.0.3325.181
Safari/537.36
```

### Demo

Comment: @ScaryWombat Typo in my code.  Used the wrong ending index for substring of terms in parentheses.  Good catch.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat You may post that as an answer if you think it is better.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting some wonky outputs that doesn't match yours, when running it in my local IDE. Also, if the input ends with closing parenthesis, it won't work on rextester either.

Comment: @eli No, the demo has both a leading and closing term with parentheses, and it works.  You need to reload this page.

Comment: Try run `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)`. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @eli I now have it [working for your sample input](http://rextester.com/FFHCD20997).

Comment: this is what i have tried String[] parts = str.split("\\s+(?![^()])"); output Mozilla/5.0
(iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10
(KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405

Comment: @keyRen The above comment belongs under your question, not under my answer.  I have given you what I believe is a working solution.  You may try it or wait for another answer.